# PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer inside routeContext. Can't set uri from property file

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have property file and I want to set uri in my route from this file:

```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

        <import resource="TransactionsParserConfig.xml"/>

        <bean id="transactionsValidator" class="com.class.TransactionsValidator"/>
        <bean id="transactionsValidator123" name="${ftp.host}"/> <!--here I can use property-->


        <routeContext id="transactionsRoutes" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
            <route id="routeFTP">
                <from uri="direct:start" />
<!--here I can NOT use property-->
                <from uri="ftps://${ftp.host}/?securityProtocol=SSL"/>

etc...

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <array>
                <value>classpath:/ftp.properties</value>
            </array>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

But looks like it's not allowed to set uri from property file. Because when I use ${ftp.host} outside the routexContext tag everething is fine. Also even Idea can't redirect me when I hit ctrl+mouseclick inside routeContext.
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camel cannot use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer inside it's Spring DSL due to Spring restrictions. There are many ways to achieve what you want. Some of them are described by [link](http://camel.apache.org/properties.html).

Comment: I used propertyPlaceholder as you recommended but I can't make it find my file in resources. now I have to put file inside folders with source files like this: <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="com/nxsystems/camel/transactionsparser/ftp.properties"/>. But I'd like to use such path:  location="classpath:src/test/resources/ftp.properties

Comment: @DmitryBorovoy If you wnat to use "classpath:" prefix - forget about specifying folder. Maven merges resources and compiled classes folders in a single classpath, so you could try something like "classpath:ftp.properties"

Answer (score 0):

You can use bean configuration mentioned below

```
<bean id="myProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>file:/properties1.properties</value>
            <value>file:/properties2.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Properties can be access in java classes like

```
@Value("${categories.insert.sql}")
private String insertQuery;
```

Properties can be accessed in camel context like

```
<setHeader headerName="signature">
    <constant>{{api.secretkey}}</constant>
</setHeader>
```

Hope this works